# Prevent showing the UI5 app internal page without successful authentication

Tags: security, navigation, sapui5, single-page-application

OpenUI5 version: 1.86
Browser/version (+device/version): Chrome Dev

Upon the authentication I validate the user session:

```js
if (isUserSessionValid) {
    const oRouter = UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
    oRouter.navTo("overview");
} else {
    this.getOwnerComponent().openAuthDialog();
}
```

If `isUserSessionValid` is true, then I forward an user to the internal page, otherwise I show the login dialog.

The problem is, however, that an user can change the value of `isUserSessionValid` in DevTools and then getting forwarded to the UI5 app internal page. Of course, due to a lack of a valid session, no piece of the business data will be displayed, just an empty UI5 app template, but I would like to prevent even such screen.

If it would be a classical webapp, I would just send an appropriate server response with a redirect to the login page (e.g. `res.redirect(403, "/login");`). But, if I understand it correctly, since I'm sending am asynchronous request, a plain `res.redirect` won't work out and I'm required to implement a redirection logic on the UI5-client, which can be manipulated and bypassed by user.

How to prevent a manipulation of a view navigation in UI5 and ensure that unauthorized user can't get any piece of the UI5-app code?

Comment: Actually you don't have to do this, everything on client is not reliable, user can change every thing on client side. Event thought you prevent it by js code, you code itself can be changed. Just make sure the server side do authentication.

Comment: @YorkChen, sure, that's why I ensure that non-authenticated person has no access to the app data.

Comment: As York Chen said, this has to be solved on the Server. If the web server detects an unauthorized user it should redirect to the login page. If you try to handle that only on client side there will always be a way to "hack" this.

Comment: So, I suppose, the "hard" redirect to the login page on case of a failed authentication is a right option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3094#issuecomment-739891005) from SAP:

> *If you want to prevent an unauthorized user from accessing the client-side code (e.g. view/controller) you need to enforce
> authorization on the server also for those static files. When bundling
> the application code you also need to ensure that those files are
> separate from the "public" files. One approach would be to have 2
> separate components, one for the public page/auth dialog and one for
> the actual application.*